# CPP checker: memsetValueOutOfRange

Tags: c++, memset, cppcheck

When I use memset function in C++ as below

```
char id[LIC_KEY_INFO_MAX_LEN + 1];

/* Create random numbers */
field[LIC_KEY_RANDOM] = createRand();

/* Create identifyer */
/* Padding in 0xff */
memset(&id, 0xffffffff, LIC_KEY_INFO_MAX_LEN);
```

And then I used CPP Check my code, it throw warning:

> Id: memsetValueOutOfRange
>   Summary: The 2nd memset() argument '4294967295' doesn't fit into an 'unsigned  char'.
>   Message: The 2nd memset() argument '4294967295' doesn't fit into an 'unsigned char'. The 2nd parameter is passed as an 'int', but the function fills the block of memory using the 'unsigned char' conversion of this value.

What's my problem.
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is *exactly* what the code checker tells you,
`0xffffffff` does not fit inside an uchar, and the second argument to memset is evaluated as uchar, so pass it `0xff`

Comment: Thanks for your help.
But when pass 0xff, the result may be not expected?

Comment: why will it not be expected? the entire memory will be filled with 0xff